# Why does Visual Studio 2008™ crash?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'm aware of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96780/why-is-visual-studio-constantly-crashing), in which the question restricts to source control issues.

In my case, it's more general. From time to time, Visual Studio will just crash randomly, even without user input.

I usually close all my files and clean my project to avoid further crashes, and I eventually crash again, without really knowing why.

Do you have some tip and tricks to avoid random crashes?

Edit : I've installed SP1, I'm running Vista on a Q6600 with 4gb RAM

Comment: Does it crash on all projects, or on one project in particular?

Comment: I've only one big solution I'm working on all day long

Comment: Just because VS2008 is a developer tool doesn't mean SO is a good place for technical support.

Comment: Where's RichB when you really need him.

Comment: I will certainly try and do a better job at editing and closing. Thank you toast.

Comment: Well,in the "related post" sections, I can see dozens of posts directly related to VS (ie how to do this or that in vs), and even some posts asking about VS bugs (like the one I linked in my post). Why aren't those close too...Can you explain me what's the difference?

Answer (score 7):

Having undocked windows can cause a crash when you start or stop debugging. There's an error report [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=362433).

Add ons can also cause crashes, especially ReSharper in my experience. You could try disabling any add ons that you can live without.

Comment: I have been dealing with that undocking bug. Jesus MS is lame on that issue. "Closed (Wont Fix)"??? Thanks for the link rossfabricant

Comment: I hate this, I'm stuck on a 17" :(

Answer (score 2):

If it's being caused by an add-on, and you happen to be running a 64-bit operating system, then there's hope yet! Microsoft released a hotfix that corrects the VS2008 crashing that ReSharper and other add-ons tend to cause. It can be found here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947841.

Answer (score 1):

When Visual Studio crashes on you, do you get a dialog asking you to send details to Microsoft?  If you do, click on "What does this report contain" and google for key parts of the header, you might find some hotfix or KB article on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at any plug-ins you're using or source control integrations.

The place I'm contracting at now uses Visual Source Safe (I know...) and the VSS integration causes me a few crashes. Especially when I've got a lot of files open, and event more so on start-up when it's checking (presumably) the status of all my open files at once.

At home I use VS2008 with the Ankh SVN plug-in and it never crashes.

Comment: Well I do use Ankh SVN .. and it (it being VS, don't know if Ankh is involved) crash quite often (several times a day)

Comment: So apart from that it's pretty much vanilla VS? What OS are you running, how much RAM? Have you installed SP1?

Answer (score 0):

You get OutOfMemoryException?
Check the size of the .suo file.
I had [problems with this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=309804) in VS 2005, but i havent reproduced it on 2008.
The .suo file would bloat, repeating a single line of code thousands, and eventually millions of times. Each time i saved, this would grow the .suo file a few megabytes.

Answer (score 0):

There are way too many reasons any program will "just crash". You are posing an inherently unanswerable question. Hell, it might even be some other software on your machine that is causing VS to crash, so no matter what you do to VS, it would never solve the real problem.

Comment: Well, there are some well known issues (see others posts in this thread). You're right, it can be something else ; but it can also be something posted here

Comment: But the answer space is way too huge. Someone who is having problems with VS crashing will not be able to easily find an answer here. You are basically creating a very broad section. This isn't a question.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically 3 reasons why VS may crash.

1) Buggy or improperly installed plug-ins.
2) Bad hardware, ie memory.  It might only crash once in a while.
3) A bug in VS.

1 is often hard to track down.

2 is also hard to track down because memory can fail intermittently.  Visual Studio is such a large program that it's much more likely to occupy bad memory than most other programs you run.

3 VS certainly has bugs, but I've never run into one where it just crashes without doing anything, so i'd doubt this.

Comment: I recently found a bug which caused Visual Studio to crash randomly on me (usually withing a couple of minutes of running it.) Microsoft are checking it out now: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=417485

Comment: Most likely not related, but VS has bugs and it does randomly crash

Comment: I didn't say VS doesn't have bugs that make it crash randomly.  I said, i've never seen on where it just crashes without doing anything.  As in, just sitting there idle.