# Visual Studio 2010 crashes frequently

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xaml, crash

I'm currently doing alot of XAML editing. It's very vanilla really but Visual Studio 2010 keeps crashing to desktop all the time. I suspect the problem lies somewhere in my code but I still feel the IDE should deal with such problems and report them without ungracefully crashing like this.

Here's the details reported by VS2010 before it CTD's...

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: devenv.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 10.0.40219.1
  Problem Signature 03: 4d5f2a73
  Problem Signature 04: (my assembly omitted)   <-- NOTE One of my assemblies here!
  Problem Signature 05: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 4f16df96
  Problem Signature 07: 3f9
  Problem Signature 08: 13
  Problem Signature 09: System.NullReferenceException
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1053

Additional information about the problem:
  LCID: 1033
```

I first suspected ReSharper and a few other add-ins but I've tried to disable them and still seeing the same crashes. I'm also not 100% sure the XAML editor is to blame but its likely because I haven't seen these crashes in any other parts of Visual Studio 2010.

Anyone else seen this?

Comment: I assume you have installed VS SP1?  Just to make sure you are on the latest.

Comment: Maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/a/96890/939213

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem (except for I have no .xaml) and this link helped:
You just need to delete .user and .suo files.

[Why is Visual Studio constantly crashing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96780/why-is-visual-studio-constantly-crashing/96890#96890)

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with VS 2010 hanging when saving. It turned out to be the SQL DataAdapter was freezing.  To solve I:

installed SP1
and 
turned off  = Tools/options/text editor/Basic/VB Specific/Pretty Listing