# Visual Studio crashes when removing reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

My 2015 Visual Studio Pro crashes every time I remove a reference from any C#  project targeting .NET 4.0. Is there a fix for this?

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015
Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01055
```

Comment: You could try this out -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96780/why-is-visual-studio-constantly-crashing

Comment: Thank you, tried those. None of those changed anything.

Comment: can you edit your config files directly and remove the offending line then go back into visual studio?

Comment: @Netferret: that's what I've been doing but that's a hassle. Now that VS2017 has come out it seems like it is working again from VS.

Comment: Does your usage of VS2017 mean this question is now effectively closed ?

Comment: Not everyone has an MSDN subscription and has switched to vs2017 especially with all the bugs it has so this question is still pertinent to my team as others are having this issue and maybe others in the SO community also.

Comment: @GregTrevellick I have the exact same problem with vs2017...  deleting the ref from the Solution Explorer and not in Project Properties seems to be a workaround

Answer (score 3):

Addition and removal of references from the project file can also be done using any text editor and editing the .proj file. Each .proj file is an XML file storing the project configuration. Just remove the reference and save the file. (A possible work-around)

The problem you mentioned don't seem to be a general issue. Visual studio may also crash for some unknown host system or project configurations.

Comment: I just used this method on a VS 2017 project that kept crashing when I removed a reference.  Simply editing the .csproj files allowed me to remove the references manually.  When I started VS 2017 back up, all of them were gone and I was able to manipulate my references normally.